# Need some clarity on for loop usage in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run below code to create pair using spark rdd, when I am the code only for one mapping it's working fine but when I am using for loop to iterate over all the elements then I am not getting the expected output.

```scala
val file = sc.textFile("filepath")
file.collect.foreach(println)
1,Abc,300                                                                       
2,Def,200
3,Xyz,400

file.map(x => x.split(",")).map(x => (x(0)->x(1))).collect.foreach(println)
```

Output is coming as expected :- 
(1,Abc)
(2,Def)
(3,Xyz)

Using for loop:-

```scala
file.map(x => x.split(",")).map(x => {
 for(i <- 0 to 2){
  x(0) -> x(i)
  }
}).collect.foreach(println)
```

Output is coming as (which is not the expected output):-
()
()
()

Expected output is:-
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
(1,Abc)
(2,Def)
(3,Xyz)
(1,300)
(2,200)
(3,400)

tried using `yield` in for loop but getting some syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me explain the output you obtain. A for loop simply returns an object of type `Unit`, regardless of what's in it. Here is a way to verify that using the REPL:

```scala
scala> val test = for(i<- 0 to 2) { i }
test: Unit = ()
```

NB: `()` is the only object of type `Unit`

If you want to change that, you need to use `yield` as you suggest it. Here is an example:

```scala
scala> val test = for(i<- 0 to 2) yield { i }
test: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 2)
```

That's more like it.

In your case, adding yield is not enough. It would yield collections of tuples like this:

```
Vector((1,1), (1,Abc), (1,300))
Vector((2,2), (2,Def), (2,200))
Vector((3,3), (3,Xyz), (3,400))
```

What you need is to use is the `flatMap` function which will flatten the collections (i.e. it transforms a RDD of collections of elements into a RDD of elements).

```scala
file.map(x => x.split(",")).flatMap(x => {
 for(i <- 0 to 2) yield {
  x(0) -> x(i)
  }
}).collect.foreach(println)
```

which gives you what you expect:

```
(1,1)
(1,Abc)
(1,300)
(2,2)
(2,Def)
(2,200)
(3,3)
(3,Xyz)
(3,400)
```